# PC no longer boots after partitioning second hard disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a PC with two identical disks.
Initially I completely ignored the second disk (/dev/sda), setting up the full system on the first one (/dev/sda). I got as far as a fully operational system.

Now I want to start using the second disk. However, if I use fdisk on /dev/sdb and I reboot, the PC is stuck.
(Side information: my first boot device is "CDROM", my second is "HARD DRIVE". Booting up I only see "Boot from CD", which is skipped for lack of a CD in the drive. After this: nothing.)

I can get back to a working system by starting from a LiveCD, and clearing the MBR of the second disk:

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1

After this, the system boots normal again.

The strange thing is that even if I just do

> fdisk /dev/sdb

and give the "w" command (=write changes to disk and quit), so without even creating any partition, the system is not able to boot anymore.

Any thoughts are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the boot order in your BIOS is "wrong", but it's not apparent because the boot loader skips unpartitioned media.

My BIOS setup offers a separate configuration option for the boot order of individual hard drives, which is sometimes messed up, after I (dis-)connect (non-boot) drives.

Comment: Now I would _never_ have thought of that! It did the trick. Thank you very much.